# Virus and threat protection not auto updating through SCCM

Tags: windows-update, sccm

Our business is managing about a hundred PCs with an undocumented installation and exploitation of  SCCM 2111, and I recently noticed a problem with the virus and threat protection on some of the computers.

The little symbol of "Virus and threat protection updates" is in yellow, and if I click on "Check for updates", it spins for a few seconds then stops, and the little yellow mark doesn't go away.

[image]

We are managing the updates through SCCM, but it looks like those updates aren't pushed to the client, and I don't understand why.

Our ADR is the following:

[image]

We also have a second ADR dedicated to Windows Defender (I think so at least?):

[image]

Both of these ADR are being successfully triggered.

What can I check to update those definitions on the client computer?

Comment: **undocumented installation and exploitation of SCCM 2111** - What does that mean, exactly?

Comment: @joeqwerty it means that the ADRs have a name that isn't really clear for me, thus making the comprehension of their usage unclear.